# Slice object with bigger transparent background

Tags: sketch-app

I made a object with size 20x13 with sketch, and I want to make the object has bigger kanvas 25x25 by adding transparent background at the back. But when I sliced it, it still in size 20x13.

Can anyone show me how to SLICE object with bigger transparent background?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

I created shape with your dimensions 23x13 px:

[image]

After I inserted slice with 25x25 dimensions.
If you want transparent background you should uncheck Background Color checkbox. Then export slice:
[image]

And we have png with desired transparent background:

[image]